# Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CustomComponentProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

I have a custom module in which I have an interface for `props` and it is extending props from a `/types/SharedProps.d.ts` file. When I import the module into an example project, the component does not contain the extended props. The module's `index.tsx` file looks like this:

```
import { SharedProps } from "./types/SharedProps";

interface CustomComponentProps extends SharedProps {
  notARobotText?: string;
  onClickCheckbox?: () => void;
  onVerificationComplete: () => void;
}

const CustomComponent = (props: CustomComponentProps ) => {
  const { notARobotText, cellsTall} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      Yo {notARobotText}, say hello. {cellsTall}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomComponent ;
```

`./types/SharedProps` looks like this:

```
export interface SharedProps {
  cellsTall?: number;
  cellsWide?: number;
}
```

The `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib/esm",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

And this is the `App.tsx` in the example project:

```
import React from "react";
import CustomComponent from "typescript-react-test";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const handleVerification = () => {
    window.alert("Verified, baby!");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomComponent 
        notARobotText="Toulouse"
        onVerificationComplete={handleVerification}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The component displays the content and requires `onVerificationComplete` and accepts `notARobotText` and `onClickCheckbox`, but it won't accept `cellsTall` or `cellsWide`, saying,

```
Type '{ notARobotText: string; onVerificationComplete: () => void; cellsTall: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CustomComponentProps.
  Property 'cellsTall' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & CustomComponentProps'.ts(2322)
```

How can I ensure `SharedProps` are accessible when the component is imported into the example project?

The index.d.ts files created after building both look like this:

```
/// <reference types="react" />
import { SharedProps } from "./types/SharedProps";
interface CustomComponentProps extends SharedProps {
    notARobotText?: string;
    onClickCheckbox?: () => void;
    onVerificationComplete: () => void;
}
declare const CustomComponent: (props: CustomComponentProps) => JSX.Element;
export default CustomComponent;
```

The custom module is in the example's package.json as `"typescript-react-test": "link:.."` The file structure for the custom module and example site looks like the following (`/lib/` is the folder generated when I build the module):

```
├─example
│  └─src
│     └─App.tsx
├─lib
│  ├─cjs
│  │  └─index.d.ts
│  └─esm
│     └─index.d.ts
└─src
   ├─types
   │  └─SharedProps.d.ts
   └─index.tsx
```

Comment: What does the compiled `d.ts` file of your custom module look like? How do you install its latest version into your example project?

Comment: I added more information. When I make changes to the module, I build the code, then go to the example project and run `yarn`. Looking at these generated `index.d.ts` files, though, there is an error saying "Cannot find module './types/SharedProps' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that `SharedProps` were being exported from a file called `SharedProps.ts`. Moving them to an `index.ts` file and making them the default export resolved the issue. My new folder structure now looks like this:

```
├─example
│  └─src
│     └─App.tsx
├─lib
│  ├─cjs
│  │  ├─types
│  │  │  └─index.d.ts
│  │  └─index.d.ts
│  └─esm
│     ├─types
│     │  └─index.d.ts
│     └─index.d.ts
└─src
   ├─types
   │  └─index.ts
   └─index.tsx
```